# Custom URL for my extension

Tags: oauth, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

Can I have a special URL like chrome://myurl or anything similar to that( like about:mypage in firefox.) for my google chrome extension.

Basically I am trying to authenticate the user using oAuth. The oAuth provider requires a callback url.

Comment: If the answer below doesn't work, let me know. I'll propose an alternative.

Comment: It will not work. Because, to register my app with the oauth provider, I have to provide callback url for my app. I have to pass the same url when making authentication request. So, I cannot rely on a dynamically created URL. I want it to be static, so that it can be same for all the user.

Comment: The extension ID can be kept [constant](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/packaging.html#upload).

Comment: I thought the ID will be generated when it is installed. Can you explain that or share a link?

Comment: I've already shared the relevant link. If you want to know the algorithm for creating the extension ID, read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1882981), by the way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension resources can be accessed by the url

```
chrome-extension://<extension-id>/<resource>
```

The Extension ID can be found on the extensions page in Chrome. Within an extension, it can be obtained programatically using the [`chrome.extension.getURL`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL) method. For example:

```
console.log(chrome.extension.getURL('/'));
// "chrome-extension://jcjnnblkpjakjflggajpdalncflgbkgg/"
```