# Keep same ID when converting from userscript in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, userscripts

I'm currently updating a userscript to a chrome extension, but since the new ID is different it won't update the old extension, but add a new one.

Is there a way to convert a userscript into a Chrome extension and keep the same ID?

Since there is no keyfile for userscript I think it could be possible,
but how ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Userscripts are converted to Chrome extensions when you load it. Follow these steps to create and maintain an extension with the same ID:

1. Install the userscript.
2. Visit `chrome://extensions/` and activate developer mode.
3. Scroll down to your user script, and find the ID:
   [image: Userscript 1.0 Description of user script ID: hjcgfecgldpgebeeflnjldogphkilfdo]
   Notice that the version of your userscript is 1.0 (by default, overriden via `@version`).
4. Next, visit the extensions directory of your Chrome/Chromium user profile. The default paths can be found [here](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory). If you launch Chrome/chromium using the `--user-data-dir=...` flag, then visit `...`.
   Once you're inside the directory, look for a directory with the ID found at 3.
5. Copy the whole directory to a **different** location, eg `/tmp/` or `%tmp%`.
6. Use the "Load unpacked extension" button, and select the first *subdirectory* of the previously copied directory: The name of this subdirectory is based on the version.
7. Scroll down to see that a converted userscript is a true extension (it loads!):
   [image: Userscript 1.0 Description of user script ID: hjcgfecgldpgebeeflnjldogphkilfdo Loaded from: /tmp/hjcgfecgldpgebeeflnjldogphkilfdo/1.0_0]

Okay, steps 6-7 are optional, they were only included to show that a userscript is converted to a true extension, with a special flag set. You can also notice the red warning about the [manifest version](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion). To fix that, edit `manifest.json`, and add `"manifest_version": 2,`. So, in our case:

> `...
>
>       "converted_from_user_script": true,
>
>       "description": "Description of user script",
>
>       "key": "eYxnPzfSPtfL3ji4nQX3ujTXpzz3YQ6dVlvHWf1gvW8=",
>
>       "name": "Userscript",
>
>       "version": "1.0",
>
>       "manifest_version": 2
>
>   }`

Now, you've got a Chrome extension which behaves like a Chrome extension with [some extra flavour](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Cross-browser_userscripting#Google_Chrome). Follow the steps from the official documentation to update your package:

> ### [Updating a package](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging#update)
>
> To create an updated version of your extension:
>
> 1. Increase the version number in `manifest.json`.
> 2. Bring up the Extensions management page by going to this URL: **chrome://extensions**
> 3. Click the **Pack extension** button. A dialog appears.
> 4. In the **Extension root directory** field, specify the path to the extension's folder—for example, `c:\myext`.
> 5. In the **Private key file** field, specify the location of the already generated `.pem` file for this extension—for example,
>      `c:\myext.pem`.
> 6. Click **OK**.
>
> ### [Uploading a previously packaged extension to the Chrome Web Store](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging#upload)
>
> You can use the Chrome Developer Dashboard to upload an extension that
>   you've previously packaged yourself. However, unless you take special
>   steps, the extension's ID in the Chrome Web Store will be different
>   from its ID in the package you created. This different ID might be a
>   problem if you've distributed your extension package, because it
>   allows users to install multiple versions of your extension, each with
>   its own local data.
>
> If you want to keep the extension ID the same, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Rename the private key that was generated when you created the `.crx` file to `key.pem`.
> 2. Put `key.pem` in the top directory of your extension.
> 3. Compress that directory into a ZIP file.
> 4. Upload the ZIP file using the [Chrome Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard).

---

### Appendum: Keeping the same ID in unpacked / packed extensions.

The extensionID of an extension can be controlled via the [`"key"` parameter in the manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/key). The easiest way to have the same ID for the unpacked and packed extension is also stated in the documentation:

> #### key This value can be used to control the unique ID of an extension, app, or theme when it is loaded during development.
>
> > Note: You don't usually need to use this value. Instead, write your
> >     code so that the key value doesn't matter by using [relative paths](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html#relative-urls) and
> >     [`chrome.extension.getURL()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL).
>
> To get a suitable key value, first install your extension from a .crx
>   file (you may need to [upload your extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) or [package it manually](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging.html)).
>   Then, in your [user data directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory), look in the file
>   `Default/Extensions/<extensionId>/<versionString>/manifest.json`. You
>   will see the key value filled in there.

When the `key` field does not exists, it's randomly generated. Then, the extensionID is generated from this key. The algorithm for generating the extensionID is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882981/google-chrome-alphanumeric-hashes-to-identify-extensions). By the nature of the algorithm, you cannot perform it in the reverse order (extensionID -> `key`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't solve my problem.
When i load the extension unpacked, it keep the same ID, but when i try to pack it, the ID change, any idea on how to keep it?

Comment: @user3 I assume that you mean the ID difference between a packed and unpacked extension? If yes, I've expanded my answer with that bit. If not, make sure that you're using the same private key to pack the extension.

Comment: @user3 Did the updated answer solve your problem? If not, what's wrong?

Comment: It didn't solve my problem but made me realize that it just was impossible ^^
Because to do what i wanted to, I should create a private key that match the key value, which (I think) is not possible.