# Adding a 'Grooveshark' entry to Google's black navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts, grooveshark

I'm trying to make a tweak to Google's black navigation bar ([**this thing at the top**](http://gyazo.com/2892f677b6c23ca7ae8a16fd14bcd358))
More specifically, I want to have a button that you can click to transpose your current search query to Grooveshark's search.

It's basically the same thing as when you search for something on Google, you hit the 'YouTube' link at the top and it searches for whatever you input on Google's website, on YouTube.

I've asked StackOverflow for help before a while back when I was new to programming (also questions pertaining to userscripts), but honestly, the respondents did most of the work for me in their replies, which I apologize for, as this was not my intention.
Because of this, I decided I wanted to make this one on my own as much as I could, and for the most part, I did (albeit with lots of Googling :)

However, now that everything is working in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fXnFF/201/), I'm having trouble 'porting' it to [**userscript**](http://pastebin.com/v9yDDJTJ) and finalizing it.
To be more specific, the Grooveshark logo does not even show up on Google's website while using my userscript on the intended pages.
I even copied part of the Google HTML source to JSFiddle to see if it would work there, and it did.
I'm still rather new to JavaScript (as in: 'I have not used it in any serious manner before today') and as such, it took me a while to put this script together.

So my questions are these:

1. How do I adapt this piece of Javascript to work on Google's website by using a userscript?
2. I added an 'alt' attribute to the Grooveshark logo, but this does not show up in my browser (chrome) while it does when viewing source or inspecting. Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Here's the userscript I have so far:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           GoogleGroovesharkBar
// @description    Adds a 'Search on Grooveshark' option to Google's black navigation bar
// @include        google.com/*
// @include        google.nl/*
// @include        https://www.google.com/*
// @include        https://www.google.nl/*
// @include        http://www.google.com/*
// @include        http://www.google.nl/*
// @require        http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js

//by Soullesswaffle
//Versions : 0.8
// ==/UserScript==

function addGroove(retrievedText) {
    var bar = document.getElementById("gbzc");
    var grooveyImage = document.createElement("img");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    var listy = document.createElement("li");
    grooveyImage.src = "http://cdn.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/nexusae0_146.png";
    grooveyImage.style.height = "28px";

    //grooveyImage.alt doesn't display in chrome for me, but when inspecting the element the alt attribute is present and correct.
    if (retrievedText === "") {
        link.href = "http://grooveshark.com";
        grooveyImage.alt = "Grooveshark";
    } else {
        link.href = "http://grooveshark.com/#!/search?q=" + retrievedText;
        grooveyImage.alt = "Search for '" + retrievedText + "' on Grooveshark";
    }

    //Nest and display everything
    link.appendChild(grooveyImage);
    listy.appendChild(link);
    listy.id = "grvshrkbtn";
    if (!document.getElementById("grvshrkbtn")) {
        bar.appendChild(listy);
    } else {
        bar.replaceChild(listy, document.getElementById("grvshrkbtn"));
    }
}

//Initialize
$(document).ready(function () {
    addGroove(document.getElementById("gbqfq").value);
});

//Watch textfield for changes
$("#gbqfq").bind("input", function () {
    addGroove($(this).val());
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why it doesn't work in Chrome:**
To run this on Firefox, you need to install the Greasemonkey add-on.  Likewise, to run this in Chrome, you need to **install [the Tampermonkey extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)**.

Chrome has limited, native support for userscripts, but it doesn't support `@require` and a bunch of other goodies.  Save yourself some hassle and use Tampermonkey.

**Avoid conflicts:** Requiring jQuery is good, but unfortunately, due to changes in Greasemonkey (and now Tampermonkey), it [can cause conflicts with some websites if the sandbox is switched off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12146445/331508).  To avoid potential conflicts, always use an explicit `@grant` to control the sandbox.

Change the end of your [metadata block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block) to:

```
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
```

**About the `alt` attribute:**
Remember that [the `alt` attribute](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/altAttribute) is only supposed to be displayed if the image doesn't load for some reason.  Is the image loading?

Perhaps you want [the `title` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-title-attribute), since it's often used for tooltips.
Change this code snippet:

```
if (retrievedText === "") {
    link.href = "http://grooveshark.com";
    grooveyImage.alt = "Grooveshark";
} else {
    link.href = "http://grooveshark.com/#!/search?q=" + retrievedText;
    grooveyImage.alt = "Search for '" + retrievedText + "' on Grooveshark";
}
```

to this:

```
if (retrievedText === "") {
    link.href = "http://grooveshark.com";
    grooveyImage.alt    = "Grooveshark icon supposed to be here";
    grooveyImage.title  = "Grooveshark";
} else {
    link.href = "http://grooveshark.com/#!/search?q=" + retrievedText;
    grooveyImage.alt    = "Grooveshark icon supposed to be here";
    grooveyImage.title  = "Search for '" + retrievedText + "' on Grooveshark";
}
```

Or just set the image's `alt` once to "Grooveshark icon", and only switch the `title`.

Comment: Thank you, I was indeed confusing 'alt' with 'title', since I wanted a tooltip.
I have also done as you suggested and: 1. Installed Tampermonkey, 2. Changed the metadata block and 3. Changed 'alt' to 'title' in my script. I also restarted chrome after the installation of Tampermonkey just in case.
Unfortunately though, the script does not seem to want to work.
When I visit Google on the included urls, the Grooveshark logo does not show up and when I click the Tampermonkey icon it says that no userscripts are running... Is it possible I messed up the includes somehow?

Comment: Yes it's possible.  I just verified that it does work with Chrome  27.0.1453.116 m and TM 3.1.3440 and the main English site (`http://www.google.com/`).  Pastebin your exact script and a URL where it doesn't work.  BTW, the first 2 `@include` lines are invalid, but they won't break the script.

Comment: We have the same version of Chrome, but my TM is version 3.2.3467.
My exact script: **http://pastebin.com/hQiSZuWE**
URL I'm using: **https://www.google.nl/** (https protocol)
And just to be clear, TM says that no scripts are running.

Comment: Upgraded my TM, your script still works on that site.  Maybe your script is in [a troublesome encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16413467/331508)?  In TM's dashboard, delete the script (and any conflicting scripts) and paste a new script in fresh from your pastebin (should be safe encoding).  Make sure the options look like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MREYy.gif).

Comment: Thank you Brock Adams, doing that worked :D
I suppose it didn't work before because I installed it through the chrome extensions page?
As a bonus, the script is indeed working as intended.
The only thing I'll have to figure out is how to get the icon to show up between the 'Translate' and 'More' entries on the bar itself.
I know that that should probably be a question on its own (or Googled), but have you got any pointers or docs you'd recommend I start reading to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, the extensions page is not where to install Tampermonkey scripts.  The good news is that TM makes it much easier to install userscripts. No more need to go through Chrome's store or drag only to the extensions page.  As for positioning...  No pointers it's just applying HTML and CSS.  Please open a new question if you need help with that.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help, I really appreciate it.
I finished up some stuff; darkened the image and added a brighter image that shows up when you hover over the image to make the end result blend, might I say perfectly, with the rest of the bar.
And to get the image to display in the bar all I had to do was change the style className to that of the other entries on the list.
If you or anyone else is interested, the final version is here: **http://pastebin.com/38bX3SGT**

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention; I replaced all the includes with a single piece of regex; It should now work on all Google search pages regardless of localization.