# How to install a userscript in chrome (added scripts cannot run)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, userscripts

I'm trying to install the basic userscript from http://pastebin.com/9CXXYYBX. I open the page with extensions list in Chrome, drag&drop my extension (copied from the pastebin link above) there and accept the permissions. So, because of the line `// @include http://userscripts.org/*` the userscript should run only on the userscripts.org, but it doesn't.

I have `Chrome 27` so as I know the userscripts should work without `Greasemonkey` installed.

What could be wrong and how to check if the userscripts are working (how to debug them so)?

Comment: The next question is different, but the answers are identical. I suggest to read http://stackoverflow.com/a/11773654/938089.

Answer (score 4):

The question is not clear. Are you having trouble installing the script, or running it, or just what it reports.

Anyway, [that script](http://pastebin.com/9CXXYYBX) works fine for me.

**To install it:**

1. **Download** the file from pastebin to your local machine.
2. **Rename** the file. It comes from pastebin named *crossvrowser_userscript_pattern.txt* (sic), but userscripts must end in `.user.js`.  So, **rename the file to `crossbrowser_userscript_pattern.user.js`**.
3. Install `crossbrowser_userscript_pattern.user.js` by dragging it to the extension page, per [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5258989/331508).

**Permission report:**

Chrome will report that the userscript can operate on all web sites, but [Chrome lies about scripts that use `@include`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16413467/331508).  It's not a problem here.

**Running the script:**

After installing that script, it runs just as expected.  When going to [a page on userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/47636), the script alerts, "Hello from the userscript," just like it should.

**If the script doesn't run:**

Go to the extensions page (`chrome://extensions/`), does the script show up?  You should see something like:

[image: Script installed]

Then when you visit [a suitable page](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/47636) you will see the alert:

[image: Script's alert]

---

You can also open Chrome's console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>) and **switch to the userscript's scope**:

[image: Switch to script scope]

Note that the id (`pfnbaeafniclcjhfkndoploalomdmgkc`) is the same as that listed on the extensions page.

---

You can then view the script source live, **add breakpoints and debug** it by following the directions in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13577880/331508).

---

[image: Debugging OP's script in action]

Comment: I do all the same you described. I have problems only with running user scripts. So the last point you mentioned is not working for me: if I go to the userscripts.org there is no alert at all. Should it alert on each page I visit, if I will remove the @include line?

Comment: Yes, if you remove the `@include` (not recommended!) **and reinstall the script**, then it will alert on each page.  See the updated answer for more.

Comment: sorry, had no time before. thank you very much for the edit! I will try at this next days (I read the edit, and I think I lost some steps you mentioned above, but I need to try and check)