# Installing Chrome extension programmatically

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, nsis

I know this has been asked pretty much and I read them all but couldn't find anything relevant to my problem so asking again.
I have made a simple chrome extension. Also packed it as crx using chrome.
I want to install it programmatically using an nsis or C++ installer.

Got some help from here http://www.chromium.org/administrators/pre-installed-extensions

But I am not sure how can I get the ID of the extension that is used.
As the ID for the same extension is different on chromes on different machine's, so one script wont work.
Also registry method didn't worked for me.

So whats the trick ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pack an extension, you also get a private key (in a `.pem` file). The extension ID is directly derived from this file (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993486/how-to-programmatically-calculate-chrome-extension-id)).

After getting a private key and extension ID, you can lock the extension ID by populating the [`"key"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/key.html) field in the manifest file.

When designing an installer, keep in mind that [Google is trying really hard](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html) to make it extremely difficult (if not impossible) for developers to install Chrome extensions that are not hosted in the Chrome Web store.

Comment: Rob, note that Chrome enterprise policy is the right solution for businesses that need off-store extensions. Also, the installation restrictions you mention apply only to stable and beta channel on Windows. Your answer's last paragraph should include these qualifications. This is a good place to start to read more about enterprise policy: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188447?hl=en.

Comment: Hi Rob,
Thanks for your help. Managed to get the Hash for my extension. 
I also updated the Key field in my manifest.json file and then used the preference file method to install it from here http://www.chromium.org/administrators/pre-installed-extensions , but still its not working. I dont know what else I am missing.

Comment: @smilepleeeaz Try to install through the registry (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html#registry). If neither method works, show the relevant files to make it easier to check if you've got a typo or anything like that.

Comment: @RobW thanks man. using registry method along with preference method got my extension listed in chrome. But it is just listed in the extension section and not showing on chrome toolbar by default. How do I make it show on chrome toolbar by default?
Here is my pref. part http://textuploader.com/1rkx

Comment: @smilepleeeaz Are you referring to the button? What's the content of HelloWorld.crx?

Comment: @RobW I'm referring to the extension icon on toolbar like this http://oi39.tinypic.com/2w5t7ix.jpg . My extension is not displaying it.HelloWorld.crx contains a manifest.json, a popup.html and icon.png and just shows popup.html with some text like "Hello World!!!!"

Comment: @smilepleeeaz As far as I know, auto-installed extensions are disabled by default. Perhaps sowbug knows a way to activate extensions by default? Ping and ask him, I'd say.

Comment: anyone figure this out? i'm trying to do this too.