# Installing and enabling external Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'm developing a Chrome extensions that would be installed simultaneously with a desktop app, as an "external extension" as [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions) call it. But I believe the extension would be disabled, and users would need to manually enable it. It's inconvenient to do this and not at all obvious how (at least to users not very familiar with extensions).

Is there a way to automatically enable the extension, or make it very easy for users to manually enable it? This was asked in the comments on [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835525/installing-chrome-extension-programmatically), but no one had an answer.

Another issue is that I think Chrome has to be restarted for the extension to be installed at all. This is obviously very disruptive from a user perspective. Is there a way around this?

Comment: What about detecting that Chrome is running and opening the extension on the web store so that the user can add it immediately? Your desktop app can warn about it and explain what to do and why beforehand.

Comment: @wOxxOm Not a bad idea. I may need to do that. But it seems like Chrome intended for there to be an easy way to install both at the same time, since they specifically created that distribution option. It's just not at all clear to an average user that the extension won't be enabled and how to enable it