# Get chrome extension's id using extension's name

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a extension which I loaded in google chrome. Now I'm writting a script from which I want to get the extension's id according to the extension's name. In this case, the extension is like a server and my script in java project is the client. 
 I need is to get the id of the extension outside, from external project

Answer (score 5):

Your extension id is supposed to remain static; It should never change, even when developing. You can simply keep a global variable.

```
var idOfOtherApplication = "ccokanilabejbblhdenlechhcggmopnp";
```

Getting an extensions id from its name would be unreliable because multiple extensions can have the same name.

To find the id of an extension go to `chrome://extensions`. To find the id of the current extension programmatically simply call one of the following:

[`var idOfThisApplication = chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@extension_id");`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n#overview-predefined)

[`var idOfThisApplication = chrome.runtime.id;`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-id)

Both of these methods require no extra permissions.

Comment: This is how to get the id extension within the extension. What I need is to get the id of the extension outside, from external project.

Comment: There is no way to get it programmatically. See my answer for more information on why. Go to `chrome://extensions` to find the id of an extension. All of this was stated in the answer. Please read carefully before making comments. Redundancy!

Comment: There is actually a  way to get it programmatically, but it is messy. You have to take the .crx file and do a whole bunch of decoding.  There are a lot of articles about it now.  I'd still avoid doing it, though.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993486/how-to-programmatically-calculate-chrome-extension-id   Also, ty to @0xcaff, that was actually the answer I needed.