# how to get alphanumeric extensions id for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Chrome - Alphanumeric hashes to identify extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882981/google-chrome-alphanumeric-hashes-to-identify-extensions)

I have written one chrome extension and I am packaging it using --pack-extension switch , it is giving me one .crx file and one .pem file. Now I wanted to install this extension on my deployment machine using windows registry, for that I wanted to know how do I get the extension id(which we get if drag and drop .crx file to chrome://extensions tab).

Answer (score 0):

**[Extension Info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#type-ExtensionInfo)** of [chrome.management API()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html) fetches extension id. However [onInstalled()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#event-onInstalled) event returns all [Extension Info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#type-ExtensionInfo) of extension installed.

**Ex:**

If extension id after packaging turns out to be **`kpddfdhkifopcepoldlgidejfnbhdbdn`**, it will be same where ever it is hosted.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks for info, but what I am looking here is different. I wanted to install my extension from crx file using windows registry, for that I need alphanumneric extn id which we get if we manually drag and drop crx file under chrome://extension tab.    How can I get this ID programatically.  Please help it is very urgent!

Comment: @AshishMittal: For example if my extension id when packed or dropped to browser under chrome://extension tab is `kpddfdhkifopcepoldlgidejfnbhdbdn` it will be **same every where in the world**, just record your extension id from your desktop and use it in server for deployement..