# How to know a Chrome extension id from a Chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I develop one Chrome extension and one Chrome app.

I launch Chrome extension with Chrome startup args "--load-extension" and also "--load-and-launch-app" for Chrome app, so I do not know the extension id of these two Chrome plug-ins. And extension on different machine may have different id.

Now I want to establish a connection between the extension and the app. I wanna use chrome.runtime.sendMessage, but I don't know how to get the id of Chrome extension in Chrome app or the id of Chrome app in Chrome extension.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your chrome extension/app manifest file defined a specific `key` key, it will have always the same ID.

For instance, let's say you've set a manifest file that looks like:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Chrome Extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC5Sq1NeTWSJlXL55lPcec6Fi5RBDBwjOsuvlypR8BkBsSN6e+nPiOBT432mA6xHDQT2SiAKK4jtoUcfdUrvR+4J5K1/3UmCrTqNQ0773sD14W+u9WDowsIwehh0Pso1jxTdoM31JRExRKBI8/w2Sup7zr40dLmV+bVAnT9ruwtuwIDAQAB",
  ...
}
```

Your Chrome Extension ID will always be `fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop`.

You may want to read the official documentation at http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/key.html to learn more about it.

And if you really want to know how it works, you can also read [Google Chrome - Alphanumeric hashes to identify extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882981/google-chrome-alphanumeric-hashes-to-identify-extensions/2050916#2050916) and http://blog.roomanna.com/12-14-2010/getting-an-extensions-id

Comment: new documentation is here (without .html): https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/manifest/key